# Expo does not support my Node version..but it's the good one

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I try to launch a basic `npm start` to develop my reactnative project and I face the following report :

> ERROR: Node.js v13.13.0 is no longer supported.
>
> expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:
>
> - =>10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
> - =>12.13.0 <13.0.0 (Active LTS)
> - =>14.0.0  <15.0.0 (Current Release)

While my `Node -v` says

> v14.7.0

Can someone please help me to understand what is going on ?I really don't understand where I can update this dependancies or I don't know how to let npm know that I have the good version of Node (installes and reinstalled...)
The log says :

```
> [...] 2 info using npm@6.14.7
> 
> 3 info using node@v14.7.0
> 
> [...]
> 
> 9 verbose lifecycle @~start: CWD: E:\appics
> 
> 10 silly lifecycle @~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'expo start' ]
> 
> 11 silly lifecycle @~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
> 
> 12 info lifecycle @~start: Failed to exec start script
> 
> 13 verbose stack Error: @ start: `expo start`
> 
> 13 verbose stack Exit status 1
> 
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
> 
> 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
> 
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
> 
> 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
> 
> 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
> 
> 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
> 
> 14 verbose pkgid @
> 
> 15 verbose cwd E:\appics
> 
> 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
> 
> 17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
> Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
> "--reset-cache"
> 
> 18 verbose node v14.7.0
> 
> 19 verbose npm  v6.14.7
> 
> 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
> 
> 21 error errno 1
> 
> 22 error @ start: `expo start`
> 
> 22 error Exit status 1
> 
> 23 error Failed at the @ start script.
> 
> 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
> additional logging output above.
> 
> 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you've installed 2 different Node Js, run:

```
which node
```

and it'll return the path there your Node Js is and you'll be able to delete if there are more than 1 version, if you're running Windows another option it's Environment Variables Path of your Node.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these devdependencies to the pakcage.json file worked for me

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-expo": "^8.2.1",
  "cross-env": "~7.0.0",
  "expo-cli": "~3.11.7",
  "jest-expo": "^37.0.0"
}
```